# Aplicacion creada en una cuenta que envie tweets a otra cuenta

Tags: php, api, twitter-api, twitter

Cree una aplicacion en la cuenta de twitter "xyz" que envia tweets usando TwitterOauth / REST API 1.1 a la misma cuenta usando este codigo y funciona bien

```
// $consumerKey    = consumerkeystring;
// $consumerSecret = consumersecretstring;
// $oAuthToken     = oauthtokenstring;
// $oAuthSecret    = oauthsecretstring; require_once('twitteroauth.php');

$tweet = new TwitterOAuth($consumerKey, $consumerSecret, $oAuthToken, $oAuthSecret);

$attachment = "image.JPG"; $image = "@{$attachment};type=image/jpeg";     

$statusMessage = 'New tweet ';
$response = $tweet->post('statuses/update_with_media', array('status' => $statusMessage,'media[]' => "$image"),true);
```

Ahora quiero crear una aplicacion usando la misma cuenta "xyz" que envie tweets a otra cuenta "abc" asi no tengo que crear una cuenta de desarrollador por cada cuenta de twitter a la que quiero enviar tweets. Como hago esto?

Comment: de lo que entiendo, es que deseas mandar menciones de la cuenta "xyz" a la cuenta "abc", por ejemplo: xyz dice: "Hola esto es un tweet" @abc, así?

Comment: @fredyfx , no , quiero usar la cuenta "xyz" para crear una aplicacion, y que esa aplicacion me permita mandar por codigo tweets a "abc", a pesar de que la aplicacion esta creada en otra cuenta